# Reading text from file and parsing

Tags: c#, regex

I'm novice in .NET
I want that my program reads text from doc, holds each string in array and then split each word by using regular expression. In console I see:
"system"
"string"
Why am I not seeing the words from the text file?

I try to create concordance, So I need to know how much times each word appears in text and number of strings where is each word . To do it, I decided to read each line, but not all text
 This is my code:

```
   string lines =File.ReadAllLines(path: @"C:\Users\Влад\Documents\Task1\ConcordanceApplication\Text.txt").ToString();
   string[] words = SplitWords(lines);
         foreach (var  word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        } 
   static string[] SplitWords(string s)
        {
            return Regex.Split(s, @"\W+");
        }
```

Comment: You haven't actually told us whats wrong. What does it do? What did you *expect* it to do? "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement, or a question.

Comment: Also, please improve your title. Your current question title could be applied to virtually every question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lines = File.ReadAllText(path: @"readme.txt");
        string[] words = SplitWords(lines);
        foreach (var  word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }

    private static string[] SplitWords(string s)
    {
        return Regex.Split(s, @"\W+");
    }
}
```

Basically use ReadAllText instead of ReadAllLines.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `string[].ToString()` in the first line.  `File.ReadAllLines` returns an array; if you call `ToString()`, you will get the text `System.String[]`, or something like that.

Try this instead:

```
string text =File.ReadAllText(path: @"C:\Users\Влад\Documents\Task1\ConcordanceApplication\Text.txt");
string[] words = SplitWords(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

'File.ReadAllLines' returns an array of strings NOT a string.
Working solution:

```
        string lines;
        using (var strReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Влад\Documents\Task1\ConcordanceApplication\Text.txt"))
        {
            lines = strReader.ReadToEnd();
            strReader.Close();
        }
        string[] words = SplitWords(lines);
        foreach (var  word in words)
            Console.WriteLine(word);
```